# Changing Quotes

Tags: quotes

What is the term for changing a quote?
For example, changing 'Who knows what evil lurks in the hearts of men?' to 'Who knows what mischief lurks in the hearts of children?'

Comment: A *joke*, a *paraody*, an [obscure] *reference*...  I don't know exactly what you're asking.  But The Shadow might know.

Comment: Also *riffing on a theme*.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the alternative to convey a similar sense as the original, it could be called a *[paraphrase](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/paraphrase)* [more often found in the verb form]

> Express the meaning of (the writer or speaker or something written or spoken) using different words, especially to achieve greater clarity:
>   *you can either quote or paraphrase literary texts*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

According to some sources, such as *[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=paraphrase)*, the term can be used even if the meaning changes

> The adaptation or alteration of a text or quotation to serve a different purpose from that of the original.